# programmatically resume task queue?

Tags: google-app-engine

So... in the admin dashboard I paused one of my queues...

When I click on that queue now I get *"Failed to load"* error message. If I try in the old task queue dashboard ui I get *"An error occured[sic] while loading details for the queue "pipeline-places"."*

By connecting to the remote api I was able instantiate the Queue and purge tasks from it. I cannot see any method to allow me to resume the queue programmatically though.

Does anybody know the 'secret' API behind the 'resume queue' button, the one which I can't get to because the dashboard ui is broken?

I have tried deploying a new version.  I assume a workaround would be to make a new queue in queue.yaml but it's annoying as then I have to change the queue name in my code and I can't return to the original name for a few days apparently.

In case it's not clear: I am talking about the live app engine, not the dev_appserver.

Comment: Hi. My name is Nikita and I'm a representative of the Google Cloud Platform Support. Currently there's no API that allows you to pause and resume task queue execution. What was an approximate amount of the tasks in the queue when you tried to resume it? As per your description, I understand that the queue is still not accessible even after the purge. Please confirm. If this is the case and you want it to be investigated further, please provide the project id so I can open a support case for you.

Comment: I think there was only one task in the queue, the task had got stuck and I wanted to delete it which was why I had paused the queue (easier to catch the task if it retries). Yes, that particular queue is still 'broken'. project id gweb-contextual-banners